# How to connect to a remote DB2 LUW database with CLI?

Tags: c, db2, database-connection, db2-luw

I am writing a C program on Linux that connects to a DB2 LUW database using the CLI driver 11.5.

I am successful in connecting to a local database on port 50000 with the following [`SQLDriverConnect`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0000584.html) call:

```c
SQLDriverConnect(
    hdbc,                /* a valid connection handle */
    NULL,                /* no Window handle */
    (SQLCHAR *)"DATABASE=testdb;UID=username;PWD=password",
    SQL_NTS,             /* the connect string is NUL-terminated */
    NULL,                /* don't care about the completed connect string... */
    0,
    NULL,                /* ...or its length */
    SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT  /* don't prompt me */
);
```

But if I specify a host name and a TCP port, as described in the documentation page I linked to:

```c
"DATABASE=testdb:localhost:50000;UID=username;PWD=password"
```

I get the error message

```
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30061N  The database alias or database name "TESTDB:LOCALHOST:50000" was not found at the remote node.  SQLSTATE=08004
```

Does anybody know how to connect to a remote DB2 database?

`db2level` gives me

```
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "*") uses 
"64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11054" with level identifier "0605010F".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.5.4.0", "s2006161200", "DYN2006161200AMD64", 
and Fix Pack "0".
Product is installed at "/usr/db2".
```

Comment: which `db2 client`  are you using (edit your question to show the plain text output of the `db2level` command.).  Normally you need to __first__ run configuration steps `catalog tcpip node`  , followed by `catalog database` followed by `terminate`, all of which you can run at the command line, and all are well documented in the Db2 Knowledge Centre.

Comment: @mao I have added the `db2level` output. I'll research the commands you gave me, thanks. It is rather cumbersome to navigate the DB2 documentation; nothing of that kind was mentioned in the CLI documentation...

Comment: When working with CLI you have to make a choice. Do you put connection string details inside the app (indirectly), or leave the connection details entirely external referencing only an alias for the database.  The `catalog tcpip node` and `catalog database` commands are for the latter approach. These commands in the Db2 Knowledge Centre online.

Comment: @mao These commands seem to work only with CLP, but that is not included in the client I downloaded. And installing that took me half a day. IBM is determined to make it hard to use their database...

Comment: Hence my question `which Db2 client`.  If you do not have the CLP, you can also directly configure this DSN and database information in an XML file called `db2dsdriver.cfg` which all current Db2 CLI clients use. Again, this is fully documented (along with various command lines to change/query this file, although you can just use an XML editor instead).

Comment: Hi Laurenz - I was just browsing your company site, and I noticed a [stonking typo error](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/services/postgresql-support/standard/product-support/) on one of the pages. In the first image it mentions EXTENDED PRODCUT support - should of course be PRODUCT. (Please ping me when you read this, so I can remove the comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the **.\samples\cli\dbconn.c** sample source code.

It has 3 different ways to connect and covers the C part...

But it seems your issue is that your connection string is mal-formed

`DATABASE=XXX:localhost:5000` is not a valid db2 cli connection string. Per the error message,  it's interpreting everything after `database=` as the DB name. `TESTDB:LOCALHOST:50000`.

Per [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/t0024166.html):

```
To make a connection to the database in a CLI application, you can perform one of the listed actions:
* Call SQLDriverConnect with a connection string that contains: 
Database=db1; Protocol=tcpip; Hostname=11.22.33.44; Servicename=56789;
```

Comment: Thanks, that is the solution. Then that is yet another bug in the documentation, because the connection string I used is described there.

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe,  yeah.. I never saw that syntax before,  but you are right,  its documented in [SqlDriverConnect](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0000584.html) .